# How do I set Hidden field values from an iFrame response with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal

I am trying to populate 3 hidden HTML files upon submitting a form based on values received from an iFrame message. This form is built using the Drupal Form API

On page load, I append 3 hidden fields to the form and setup the eventListener

```
setupMonerisHiddenFormElements() 
{

    $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
        id: 'responseCode',
        name: 'responseCode',
    }).appendTo('form');     

    $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
        id: 'dataKey',
        name: 'dataKey',
    }).appendTo('form');     

    $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
        id: 'errorMessage',
        name: 'errorMessage',
    }).appendTo('form');        
}

window.onload = function()
{

    is_production = Drupal.settings.moneris_payment_processor.is_production;
    qa_gateway_url = Drupal.settings.moneris_payment_processor.qa_gateway_url;
    prod_gateway_url = Drupal.settings.moneris_payment_processor.prod_gateway_url;

    gateway_url = ((is_production) ?  qa_gateway_url : prod_gateway_url);

    if (window.addEventListener)
    {   
        window.addEventListener("message", processMonerisResponse, false);
    }
    else
    {
        if (window.attachEvent)
        {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", processMonerisResponse);
        }
    }

    setupMonerisHiddenFormElements();

 }
```

I can see these fields are being added on the form. This is not the problem.

When the form gets submitted the function submitMonerisIframe() is called by this Drupal form attribute:

```
$form['#attributes'] = array('OnSubmit' => 'submitMonerisIframe();');
```

Here i am posting the message and can see that my processMonerisResponse() function is being called (see below)

```
function submitMonerisIframe()
{
    var monFrameRef = document.getElementById('monerisFrame').contentWindow;    
    monFrameRef.postMessage('',gateway_url);
}
```

I have added my debugging. When I submit the form, I can see that the hidden values are being set correctly.

```
function processMonerisResponse(e)
{
    console.log(e.data);
    this.respData = eval("(" + e.data + ")");

    $('#responseCode').attr('value',respData.responseCode);
    $('#errorMessage').attr('value',respData.errorMessage);
    $('#dataKey').attr('value',respData.dataKey);

    console.log("---------- RESPONSE -----------------");
    console.log("responseCode: " + $('#responseCode').attr('value'));
    console.log("errorMessage: " + $('#errorMessage').attr('value'));
    console.log("dataKey: " + $('#dataKey').attr('value'));
    console.log("-------------------------------------");

    e.preventDefault();

 }
```

Result from the console:

{"responseCode":"001","dataKey":"ot-QQHTTg4EDGgBa4mkc0KrCGkPJ","bin":"378734"}

---------- RESPONSE -----------------

responseCode: 001

errorMessage:

dataKey: ot-QQHTTg4EDGgBa4mkc0KrCGkPJ

---

But when I inspect the $_POST[] data the hidden fields are there but are empty.

I spent hours trying different things but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using `$(#responseCode).val(respData.responseCode)` ?

Comment: Thanks Tyr - Please see my response to Charlefti's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting *attribute* `value` is not the same as setting the *property* `value`.

When you submit the form it is the value *property* that gets submitted.

Use `val()` instead of `attr()` to set or get the `value`.

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2sxs2avo/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Charle. I changed my code to use `val()` instead of `attr()`. I can see using the debug I'm writing to the console that the values are being set correctly but again nothing is set in the $_POST array.

Comment: I don't see anyhwere that data gets submitted to server

Comment: The data is submitted from the Drupal form. Do I need to do a second submit after I attach these fields? My understanding was that the form OnSubmit() would need to complete before the submit happens?

Comment: form should only submit once. If those fields aren't set before the form submits that would be a problem

Comment: Interesting! I have just added $('#manual-payment-form').submit(); after I set the values and they are not available in the $_POST array. Another question. Is there any issues with me doing that? I can see that 2 Posts are being completed.

Comment: I don't know why it posted twice the first time. But I have just tested 10 more times with valid and invalid inputs and it only posted once each time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is very fragmented i build up a testfile.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)) {
        print_r($_POST);
    }
?>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function setupMonerisHiddenFormElements() 
{

    $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
        id: 'responseCode',
        name: 'responseCode',
    }).appendTo('form');     

    $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
        id: 'dataKey',
        name: 'dataKey',
    }).appendTo('form');     

    $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
        id: 'errorMessage',
        name: 'errorMessage',
    }).appendTo('form');        
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setupMonerisHiddenFormElements();
    $('#responseCode').val('response for responseCode');
    $('#dataKey').val('response for dataKey');
    $('#errorMessage').val('response for errorMessage');
});

</script>

<form action="file.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Result of the $_POST array:

```
Array (
    [submitbutton] => submit
    [responseCode] => response for responseCode
    [dataKey] => response for dataKey
    [errorMessage] => response for errorMessage
)
```

Can you show us the code for your post handling?

Comment: I commented again on Charlie's answer to say if I submit the form again it works. Right now, all I am doing with the post is priting the response to the screen using the `drupal_set_message()` function. `drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($_POST, true) .'</pre>');  `

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve? You have a nested iframe, which sends the message to the parent window?